# Chrome 60 enable logging in headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geb

I'm using Geb (Selenium & Webdrivers 3.40) with Chrome 60 on Windows 7 Enterprise.

My `GebConfig.groovy` defines a `chrome` environment that configures Chrome with the following start arguments `--headless --disable-gpu --disable-plugins --enable-logging --v=1`.

```
environments {

    chrome {
        ChromeDriverManager.instance.setup()
        driver = {

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
            options.addArguments('--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-plugins', '--enable-logging', '--v=1')

            def capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)

            def driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities)
            return driver
        }
    }
}
```

According to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236425/how-to-enable-logging-for-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-12-04) Chrome should log to `~/.config/google-chrome` but after running my Geb tests I cannot find any log on that path. I'm trying to enable the log since I have trouble connecting a internal website using HTTPS and I need more information on what is going wrong.

Can you tell me how to enable the log correctly and where I can find Google Chromes log output?

**Update 1:**

According to this [documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#Windows) the log is saved under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\chrome_debug.log`. I found that log but its empty. 
Since I cannot seem to connect over SSL I wonder how I can get Chrome to tell me where the problem lies. Any ideas?

**Update 2:**

It seems that whenever I ran the tests in `--headless` mode and accessing an internal HTTPS URL I get the following Dummy HTML from the Web Driver.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre><iframe name="chromedriver dummy frame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

In the servers log I cannot see any incoming HTTP request. Does anyone know such a behaviour?

Comment: First verify manually that the log works. Because I doubt it logs https and other details. Also the log file is `chrome_debug.log` created in the profile directory. Refer to https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Comment: I am unable to find the chrome_debug.log file when using headless mode. Did you face the same issue?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging), the logging depends on the platform:

On Linux:

```
--enable-logging=stderr --v=1
```

On Windows:

```
--enable-logging --v=1
--enable-logging=stderr --v=1 > log.txt 2>&1  # Seems to capture more output
```

I've tested on Linux and it works fine.

The logs are saved on the Chrome's user data directory.

Comment: is there a way to disable the logging ?

Comment: `--enable-logging=stderr --v=1` worked for me on OSX with Chrome 109.

Answer (score 0):

I think your last parameter should be

```
'--enable-logging=v=1'
```

Combining the two.

Also the debug log I find is in the application install directory.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\<chrome version>
```

called

```
chrome_debug.log
```

Comment: Does not work for me. The following documentation states it as follows

> To enable logging, launch Chrome with these command line flags:
> `--enable-logging --v=1`

https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Comment: On windows these are the command line switches for chrom which work for me; chrome --enable-logging --v=1 --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom https://www.some-url.com/

Comment: Can you try adding it as one argument without the = ? so '--enable-logging --v=4'

Comment: Where does `--dump-dom some-url.com` dumps the DOM to?

Comment: To stdout although you can save the dom to a file by adding '> filename.html' to the end. That will save it in the chrome executing directory, so the same folder as I added to my answer.

Comment: On Chrome 63, when using these logging options on normal Chrome, it logs to a file in the user application data directory, but when using headless mode, it writes it to stderr instead.

Comment: @reduckted: Have you been able to solve this issue? I also find that in headless mode, it is writing to stderr and I am unable to capture that when using Selenium. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: @Phani I don't think so, no. I was running Chrome locally via a command prompt, and was able to see the stderr output, so I didn't look any further into it.